# Dynamic routing not working as expected in Nextjs

Tags: django, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am trying to create a dynamic route in nextjs but I am getting page not found error
The page loads only when I give the url with the exact pathname of the page
I have a Django Backend server set up I just call The RestApis

Here is the error
[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5JTy.png)

here is the page when I pass the exact url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny9Mn.png)

This is how I created the route in the app directory
[app/something/[id]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5uwd.png)

And this is the screen I want to render
[page.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEpEx.png)

I am expecting to a dynamic url from where i can extract the id through params

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using slug as [id]

So Your URL path should be like this, (1234 will be value of id)

```
http://localhost:3000/something/1234
```

instead of this

```
 http://localhost:3000/something/[id]
```

Reference Link : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: Hi Krushna when i try that url  http://localhost:3000/something/1234 i am getting the error that page not found but when i use http://localhost:3000/something/[id] this exact url then the page is rendered . Please check my Error screen Image link and the link next to it